# text to html script

Tags: ruby

Does anyone have or know of a Ruby script that converts text to html?

Example:

I have a file that contains the following text:

Host Name

```
Info1
Line1
Info2
Line2
```

I want to have ruby convert it to the following html output

### **Host Name**

***Info1***
    Line1
  ***Info2***
    Line2

I tried running RedCloth but got the following error:

The program can't start because msvcrt-ruby18.dll is missing

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Convert it by doing what exactly?

Comment: Ehrm, converting to html == adding asterisks on every second line?

Comment: I wanted to put in an H1 header on hostname and want to bold and Italicize the info1 line.

Comment: Sorry the asterisks were suppose to be bold and Italics

Comment: @goruby - please edit this question enclose the 2 code samples using the 'Code Sample' button in the rich text editor or by indenting each line by 4 spaces in addition to any existing indentation.

Comment: You really need to clarify your question.  If I put <p> and </p> tags around your text that makes it html.  But obviously that's not what you want.

Comment: I have added additional clarification. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends upon what you mean by "text to HTML."  There are several "web text generators" that convert easy-to-read free text with minimal markup (asterisks to indicate bold, double-spaced paragraphs get surrounded in <p> tags, etc).  The most common, for Ruby, are [Redcloth](http://redcloth.org/), which implements Textile free text, and Bluecloth, which implements Markdown.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I tried running RedCloth, but got the following error: program can't start because msvcrt-ruby18.dll is missing